# Use Tab-key on a multiline text field in swt?

Tags: java, text, swt, tabs, multiline

How do I prevent a multi-line text field from "stealing" tab-key presses?

I mean: I'd like to use TAB to cycle between the elements of a window, but when I enter the multiline text, TAB becomes a "normal" key, and simply inserts tabulators into the text I'm typing.

How do I handle this? Should I write some custom listener, or can I change the behaviour of the component by using an SWT constant?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

SWT defines a mechanism for implementing this kind of behaviour using the TraverseListener class. The following snippet (taken from [here](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/~checkout~/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet241.java)) shows how:

```
Text text1 = new Text(shell, SWT.MULTI | SWT.WRAP);
text1.setBounds(10,10,150,50);
text1.setText("Tab will traverse out from here.");
text1.addTraverseListener(new TraverseListener() {
    public void keyTraversed(TraverseEvent e) {
        if (e.detail == SWT.TRAVERSE_TAB_NEXT || e.detail == SWT.TRAVERSE_TAB_PREVIOUS) {
            e.doit = true;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Add a keystroke listener to the textfield or textarea and implement a special handler for <kbd>TAB</kbd>. I've seen this 'tab catching' on Swing applications too and it's usually annoying.

You could offer another handler for <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd> which then would insert a `\t`, if you still want to allow tabs in the textfield.