# Java - JTextArea - modifying after giving away focus?

Tags: java, swing, focus, jtextarea, timing

Here is a simple version of my code:

```
JTextArea textareaA = new JTextArea(...);
JTextArea textareaB = new JTextArea(...);

textareaA.addModificationListener(new Modification Listener()
{
    public void modified(Modifiable arg0){
        if (textareaA.getValue().contains("\t"))
        {
           textareaA.setValue(textareaA.getValue().trim());
           textareaB.getTextComponent().requestFocusInWindow();
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is, when I try different ways to change the value of A, B never gets the focus. If I turn off the focusable of A, I can't turn it back on. I need to remove the tab from A, then give focus to B, allowing the user to click back to A if needed, and the tab be gone. The above code causes the focus to stay in A, even though I had B request it. Is this a timing issue maybe?

Thank you!

Comment: So what you're really asking for is the ability to tab toggle between text fields?

If so, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161714/use-tab-key-on-a-multiline-text-filed-in-swt

Comment: ok... what is this `addModificationListener`? Do you have a subclass of javax.swing.JTextArea with your own listener?

Comment: yes I do, but it works just as you would expect.

Comment: `yes I do, but it works just as you would expect` but you have to create own method and override `if (textareaA.getValue().contains("\t"))` too

Comment: Is there any reason you aren't just using a DocumentListener?

Comment: it recognizes the tab, yes. it will tab to B as you would expect, but then when you click back to A, the tab is still there. I changed the lines where it has A.setvalue() to A.getTextComponent().setText() and no difference. I'm not sure why it won't yank the tab out, but it might have more to do with the structure of those custom jcomponents than the focus issue itself.

Comment: It would really help if you just tell us what you're trying to do. I can only guess: 1. set a Tab order in your form. 2. Trim the value in Textfield A after editing is done. Beside that, setting a value won't change the focus.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understood your question, you want a user to be able to type "Tab" and switch to the next textarea. You also want to trim the last "Tab" entered.

Besides the fact that if you type a "Tab" in the middle of the text, it will not get removed, the next code (based and elaborated from your own) seems to do what you want:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

public class Test {

    protected void initUI() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Test dialog synch");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        final JTextArea textareaA = new JTextArea(24, 80);
        final JTextArea textareaB = new JTextArea(24, 80);
        textareaA.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY, 1));
        textareaB.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY, 1));
        textareaA.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                modified();
            }

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                modified();
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                modified();
            }

            public void modified() {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (textareaA.getText().contains("\t")) {
                            textareaA.setText(textareaA.getText().trim());
                            textareaB.requestFocusInWindow();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        panel.add(textareaA, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(textareaB, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test().initUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 but searching into Document, otherwise is possible to lost bias possition